# export 'isFakeTouchstartFromScreenReader' was not found in '@angular/cdk/a11y'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-management, angular-cdk

I suddenly get the following errors in my Angular 11 project:

```
Error: ./node_modules/@angular/material/fesm2015/core.js 1091:45-77
"export 'isFakeTouchstartFromScreenReader' was not found in '@angular/cdk/a11y'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/material/fesm2015/menu.js 786:17-49
"export 'isFakeTouchstartFromScreenReader' was not found in '@angular/cdk/a11y'
```

What I tried:

```
ng add @angular/material
npm i @angular/material
npm i
```

Comment: I am getting the same error using angular 11.2.0. I tried running npm i @angular/cdk but I'm still getting this issue.

Comment: @franzke you should try removing node_modules as Remco suggested as well. And try using `ng add @angular/material`

Comment: I fixed it by updating angular packages via `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core @angular/cdk --force --create-commits`

Answer (score 5):

All you need to is `npm i @angular/cdk`.
It appears to be a version mismatch and the command above should update the cdk to the corresponding version.
Please correct me if I'm wrong/it changes.

Comment: Thanks. The following fix it for me:
`npm uninstall @angular/cdk && npm i @angular/cdk@^11`
_if someone is using Angular 12, it will be @angular/cdk@^12_

Answer (score 1):

I got this too when messing around with versions. Throw away `node_modules` folder, make sure your versions in `package.json` are in sync, and `npm i`